# Is there a way to give an iOS app to one person through Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have built this app for my cousin. Is there a way I can give it to him and only him? I know I can build it directly on his phone, but I believe that will only work for 30 days after the build, and he lives 8+ hours away so I cannot keep doing that. Any answers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build the app directly to his phone, the app will expire after 1 week or 1 year depending if you have a free developer account or a paid account. If he has a Mac accessible, he could download Xcode and you could send him the source project for him to build it to his own phone.

You could also use Apple's TestFlight service, which requires a paid developer account. This is probably the easiest and most Apple-approved method, but the apps will expire after 60 days unless you submit an update.

You could use also use a third-party distribution service like [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/) or [buddybuild](https://www.buddybuild.com).

Comment: You are just pointless steering the OP away from easy and simply app delivery methods that Apple provides, I am assuming because of the $99 developer fee involved...yes?

Comment: I didn't suggest TestFlight because TestFlight builds expire after 60 days.

Comment: really, you didn't mention Test Flight because the builds expire after 60 days? That is the reason? lol

Comment: I'll update my answer to include TestFlight, along with its pros and cons. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: He actually does have a Mac, I didn't think about giving him the project file... I think I'll do that! Thanks!

Comment: He actually does have a Mac, I didn't think about giving him the project file... I think I'll do that! Thanks!

Comment: @AlanWilson Great! Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so others in the future can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **free** Apple Developer account you can "**side-load**" the app onto your friend's device and it will last **7 days**, it used to be 60 days but Apple changed this.

If you have a **paid, $99 a year Apple developer** account you can "**side-load**" the app onto your friends device and it will be on available for your friend's device for **60 days**.

The ideal solution is to use Apple's **TestFlight**, than you can deliver multiple versions of your app quickly to your friend's device. Your friend simply installs the TestFlight app, to get your apps.

You can register your friends' Apple Ids under different roles such as Testers, Advertisers/Marketers, Administrators and control the apps they have visibility to.

Apple' TestFlight requires the $99 a year developer license, it is worth it though, if the $99 a year seems like an unnecessary expense than the app probably is not worth developing is the way I rationalize the expense.

Also, with **TestFlight**, **app expiration is not a big deal** because when the app is near expiration you simply provide a new build and your friend can get latest changes.

With 'side-loading" you have to keep physically getting your friend's device to deliver versions of the app and this gets old quick and goes strongly against the grain of agile development/rapid feedback of changes.

Comment: TestFlight builds expire after 60 days and require the $99 fee, as you mentioned.

Comment: This would be the best option, it's just that since personal training is a competitive thing, he wanted to be the only one to have this app. That's the only reason I don't want to put it on the app store

Comment: @AlanWilson I did not suggest putting it on the app store anywhere in my answer

Comment: @AlanWilson TESTFlight is a Apple's beta testing and app testing program, you can have to explicitly give permission to each person you want to share the app with, no one else can access the app except your friend